# How to turn off jboss signature?

Tags: apache, security, jboss, jboss5.x, appserver

Is there a way to turn off Jboss signature . Suppose the url is mis-spelled an error message "The requested resource (Invalid path /test was requested) is not available" , below this 
 server name and version is displayed (JBoss Web /2.1.1.0) .. I have read that hiding server name and version is a good security practice...
I am using Jboss 5.1

Answer (score 0):

If it's any webapp then the best way is to write an error jsp or html and redirect to that page for whatever even in case of web-console,jmx-console etc.

For example, like this in web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/the404_page.html</location>
</error-page>
```